# PostgreSQL with datafile on NAS

Tags: postgresql, nas

Is there someone tried to run PostgreSQL server with mounted datafile on NAS server? Can you share did you faces some performance issues or other problems?

Comment: @VaoTsun I also saw some but from 2003. What are the recommendations in 2018?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html#CREATING-CLUSTER-MOUNT-POINTS

> Many installations create their database clusters on network file
>   systems. Sometimes this is done via NFS, or by using a Network
>   Attached Storage (NAS) device that uses NFS internally. PostgreSQL
>   does nothing special for NFS file systems, meaning it assumes NFS
>   behaves exactly like locally-connected drives. If the client or server
>   NFS implementation does not provide standard file system semantics,
>   this can cause reliability problems (see
>   http://www.time-travellers.org/shane/papers/NFS_considered_harmful.html).
>   Specifically, delayed (asynchronous) writes to the NFS server can
>   cause data corruption problems. If possible, mount the NFS file system
>   synchronously (without caching) to avoid this hazard. Also,
>   soft-mounting the NFS file system is not recommended.
>
> Storage Area Networks (SAN) typically use communication protocols
>   other than NFS, and may or may not be subject to hazards of this sort.
>   It's advisable to consult the vendor's documentation concerning data
>   consistency guarantees. PostgreSQL cannot be more reliable than the
>   file system it's using.

and also check discussions in mail archive:
https://www.google.ie/search?ei=IUe7WtPgBuiZgAbUjY6wAQ&q=www.postgresql.org+NAS&oq=www.postgresql.org+NAS&gs_l=psy-ab.3...171931.171931.0.172294.1.1.0.0.0.0.54.54.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ZQOg3b7OmDk

Comment: I also saw it. But I'm planning to use iSCSI not NFS.

Comment: concerns should remain the same I suppose

Comment: @VaoTsun can you please summarize in a beginner's terms for what your answer is saying?

Comment: in beginners terms - don't use NFS for db storage. as beginner you will fail in fight with possible problems. So - sure, use it if you can manage it (if you can make it reliable or dont care, or know all concerns and find it ok), but if not - dont

Comment: It's important to note that the NFS Considered Harmful article was written in year 2000 and things have changed in the last 18+ years.